# How to connect to alfresco using Alfresco api?

Tags: angular, api, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/tutorials/working-with-data-table/

here is my mydatatable.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlfrescoApiService } from '@alfresco/adf-core';
import { ObjectDataTableAdapter, ObjectDataRow } from '@alfresco/adf-core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mydatatable',
  templateUrl: './mydatatable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mydatatable.component.scss']
})
export class MydatatableComponent implements OnInit {

  data = new ObjectDataTableAdapter([],[]);

  
  constructor(private apiService: AlfrescoApiService) {

    let api: any = this.apiService.getInstance();
  //   let api2: any = this.apiService;

  api.webScript.executeWebScript(
    'GET',
    'people',
    [],
    null,
    '/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1',
    null
 ).then(
    (response: any) => {
       let results = [];
       for (var entry of response.list.entries) {
          results.push({
             id: entry.entry.id,
             firstName: entry.entry.firstName,
             lastName: entry.entry.lastName,
             status: 'green',
             icon: 'material-icons://accessibility'
          });
       }
       this.data.setRows(results.map(item => {
          return new ObjectDataRow(item);
       }));
    }
 );

}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  onRowClick(event: any) {
    alert('We just clicked row id: ' + event.value.obj.status);
  }

}
```

and mydatatable.component.html

```
<adf-datatable 


(rowClick)="onRowClick($event)"
  [data]="data">
  <data-columns>
    <data-column 
      key="icon" 
      type="image" 
        [sortable]="false">
      </data-column>
    <data-column 
      key="firstName" 
      title="First Name">
    </data-column>
    <data-column 
      key="lastName" 
      title="Last Name" 
      class="full-width name-column">
    </data-column>
    <data-column key="status" title="Status">
        <ng-template let-entry="$implicit">
          <span *ngIf="entry.data.getValue(entry.row, entry.col) == 'red'" style="background-color: red; width: 20px; height: 20px"></span>
          <span *ngIf="entry.data.getValue(entry.row, entry.col) == 'green'" style="background-color: green; width: 20px; height: 20px"></span>
        </ng-template>
      </data-column>

  </data-columns>
</adf-datatable>
```

when I compile I get nothing on the http://localhost:4200/mydatatable. However in the console I get this error:

```
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeWebScript')
    at new MydatatableComponent (mydatatable.component.ts:22)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.MydatatableComponent_Factory [as factory] (mydatatable.component.ts:55)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:4274)
    at instantiateRootComponent (core.js:8026)
    at createRootComponent (core.js:13542)
    at ComponentFactory$1.create (core.js:24101)
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.js:10205)
    at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.js:5178)
    at RouterOutlet.ngOnInit (router.js:5114)
    at callHook (core.js:3281)
```

and this is my app.config.json:

```
{
 "$schema": "../node_modules/@alfresco/adf-core/app.config.schema.json",
 "ecmHost": "{protocol}//{hostname}{:port}",
 "bpmHost": "{protocol}//{hostname}{:port}",
 "providers": "ALL",
 "authType": "BASIC",
 "identityHost": "{protocol}//{hostname}{:port}/auth/realms/alfresco",
 "oauth2": {
   "host": "{protocol}//{hostname}{:port}/auth/realms/alfresco",
   "clientId": "alfresco",
   "scope": "openid",
   "secret": "",
   "implicitFlow": true,
   "silentLogin": true,
   "redirectSilentIframeUri": "{protocol}//{hostname}{:port}/assets/silent-refresh.html",
   "redirectUri": "/",
   "redirectUriLogout": "/logout"
 },
 "application": {
   "name": "GED ADF"
 },
 "languages": [
   {
     "key": "en",
     "label": "English"
   },
   {
     "key": "fr",
     "label": "French"
   },
   {
     "key": "de",
     "label": "German"
   },
   {
     "key": "it",
     "label": "Italian"
   },
   {
     "key": "es",
     "label": "Spanish"
   },
   {
     "key": "ja",
     "label": "Japanese"
   },
   {
     "key": "nl",
     "label": "Dutch"
   },
   {
     "key": "pt-BR",
     "label": "Brazilian Portuguese"
   },
   {
     "key": "nb",
     "label": "Norwegian"
   },
   {
     "key": "ru",
     "label": "Russian"
   },
   {
     "key": "zh-CN",
     "label": "Simplified Chinese"
   }
 ],
 "logLevel": "trace"
}
```

PS: when I try the same url on postman it works
I'm using node v14.17.1 and npm 8.3.2

What could be the problem, and how I can fix it

Thank you in advance

Comment: add some console.log on the variable that matches where the error is said to happens in the exception stack, otherwise i'm afraid we can't guess just from this.

Comment: Please share your app.config.json

Comment: @VikashPatel I added it

Comment: "ecmHost": "{protocol}//{hostname}{:port}",

Change this property to your alfresco host and port

And there is one more file of proxy there also you have to update the alfresco host & port

Comment: @VikashPatel I did it and now I have another error besides the first one wich is "Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc." PS: I tried to solve it by placing the enablecors jar file and it didn't work

Comment: Which alfresco version you are using?

Comment: @VikashPatel I'm using Alfresco community 7.0 installed with zip. and generated the latest ADF and also tried it on the Alfresco-content-app

Comment: @VikashPatel  and if I use webscript directly like this.apiService.getInstance().webScript.executeWebScript(......) I get the following error: error TS2339: Property 'webScript' does not exist on type 'AlfrescoApi'.

Comment: follow the below answer by Sanjay, it should work.

Comment: @VikashPatel the problem is that I cannot use webscript it says error TS2339: Property 'webScripti' does not exist on type 'AlfrescoApi'

Comment: webScripti there is spelling mistake use "webScript" keyword

Comment: and use the below example as explained below, that will work.

Comment: @VikashPatel The tutorial may be out of date. I think the webscript has been deprecated from newer versions of the ADF. I used EcmUserService and it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use below way:

1. By using AlfrescoApiService

   constructor(private apiService: AlfrescoApiService) {
   this.apiService.getInstance().webScripti.executeWebScript('GET',
   'api/task-instances?authority=' +   this.authService.getEcmUsername())‍
   }
2. https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/core/services/people-content.service/

Comment: The tutorial may be out of date. I think the webscript has been deprecated from newer versions of the ADF. I used EcmUserService and it worked. thank you